# Variance bound of a functional

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, measure-concentration

$X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d standard normal random variables.

$a_1,\ldots, a_n$ are constants with $a_i \in [\kappa_1, \kappa_2]$ for all $i$ and $\kappa_1>0$.

$\hat c_n$ is given as the solution to the equation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{c -X_i^2}{(c+a_i)^2}=0. $$

Can we prove that $$ \operatorname{Variance} (\hat c_n)=O(n^{-1}) \text{ as } n \to \infty.$$

Note that the above can be proved easily when all $a_i$' s are equal. What will happen in the general case?

Comment: Are you claiming that this equation always has a unique solution? That doesn't look obvious.

Comment: The equation has a unique solution as it arrives from minimizing the convex criterion $$ \sum_i \log(c a_i^{-1}+1)+(1+X_i^2)/(ca_i^{-1}+1)$$

Comment: "standard" = "standard Gaussian" or something else?

Comment: Also $t\mapsto \log t+\frac Kt$ is *not* convex

Comment: Oh sorry...i was wrong on this...will need to modify the problem accordingly..thanks for pointing out this issue...

Comment: No problem. Once you figure out what exactly you want to ask, edit the question and someone will think of it. It doesn't look terribly complicated but it would be nice to have all dots over i's in the formulation first :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not rigorous, but if one constant $a_1$ is small but the others $a_i$ are large, say $a_i\gg n$ for $i>1$ then it seems the $i>1$ terms are negligible and $c\approx X_i^2$, so $\mathrm{Var}(\hat c)$ does not go to 0.

Comment: The constants $a_i$ are all bounded.